# Why would this script not work?

Tags: lua, roblox

The following script breaks between print("2") and print("3") because it cannot find the variable "tag". How would I fix this?

```
local Humanoid = script.Parent.Zombie -- Or Zombie Or Whatever 
function PwntX_X() 
    print("1")
    local tag = Humanoid:findFirstChild("creator")
    print("2") 
    if tag ~= nil then 
        print("3")
        if tag.Value ~= nil then 
            print("4")

            local Leaderstats = tag.Value:findFirstChild("leaderstats") 
            print("5")
            if Leaderstats ~= nil then 
                print("6")
                Leaderstats.Cash.Value = Leaderstats.Cash.Value + 5
                print("7")
                wait(0.1)`enter code here`
                script:remove()
            end 
        end 
    end 
end 
Humanoid.Died:connect(PwntX_X)
```

I already have a script for the leaderboard that works 100%. This script is being used for a game called "ROBLOX". Thanks!

Comment: The more Lua way to check for not nil is: if not tag then ... end

Comment: Ok I will change it.

Comment: And to answer your actual question, the function findFirstChild("creator") is returning nil, so you will have to post the code for that function to have people help.

Comment: Regarding `not tag` vs `tag ~= nil`, `nil` and `false` are falsey so as long as you don't need to distinguish between them, `not tag` is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, first off, scriptinghelpers.org was created as a service similar to stackoverflow specifically for Roblox, I suggest next time, you ask there, now on to stuff;

```
-- If you have further problems, My Roblox username is 'ZeroBits' (REMOVE THIS LINE)

DEBUG = true -- Debug Print, so you can disable it when you're done.
local function print_D(t)
    if DEBUG == true then warn(t) end end
print_D("DEBUG MODE, Switch Debug Value to False when finished")

local Humanoid = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Zombie") -- We'll use FindFirstChild() here
--if not Humanoid then -- Uncomment this statement if you want it to affect objects named Humanoid as well
--    Humanoid = script.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
--end
function HumanoidKilled() -- Renamed the function to be a little less cringeworthy 
    print_D("1") -- switched these print statements with the Print_D() function
    local tag = Humanoid:FindFirstChild("creator") -- Capitalized the first letter in FindFirstChild()
    print_D("2") 
    if not tag then 
        warn("No Tag Found check Humanoid and weapon script")  --if this prints, there's either no tag, or a serious problem, and you should check the humanoid object for a tag, or make sure the weapons you use actually generate tags.
    else -- changed 'if tag ~= nil then' to 'if not tag then 'do stuff' else' to simplify the code, and add an else statement early on.
        print_D("3")
        if tag.Value then -- removed '~= nil' because it's just useless clutter
            print_D("4")
            local Leaderstats = tag.Value:findFirstChild("leaderstats") 
            print_D("5")
            if Leaderstats ~= nil then 
                print_D("6")
                Leaderstats.Cash.Value = Leaderstats.Cash.Value + 5
                print_D("7")
                wait(0.1)
                script:Destroy() -- switched remove() to Destroy(), remove() is deprecated
            end 
       end 
    end
end 
Humanoid.Died:connect(HumanoidKilled)
```

This fixes all the problems in the script, and makes it more efficient. if there are still problems, it's either in the tag creation script, the tags aren't stored in the humanoid, or the tags aren't named 'creator'

also, I switched over the print statements to a print_D function, which uses warn() rather than print() there's almost no difference, except that the debug text will appear yellow in the console, rather than white.

> script is being used for a game called "ROBLOX". Thanks!

It's for a game On Roblox, not a game called Roblox, what you said is akin to saying; I made this mod for Source Engine, when you actually made the mod for Half-Life 2